# Unable to generate makefile for basic PETSc program

Tags: c++, makefile, cmake, mpi, petsc

I have a very basic program using PETSC

```
 #include "PETSC/petsc.h"
 #include "PETSC/petscsys.h"
 #include "PETSC/petscmat.h"

 int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
     PetscMPIInt    rank,size;
     PetscInitialize(&argc,&argv,0,0);
     MPI_Comm_size(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,&size);
     MPI_Comm_rank(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,&rank);
     PetscPrintf(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,"Number of processors = %d, rank = %d\n",size,rank);
     PetscSynchronizedPrintf(PETSC_COMM_WORLD,"synchronized rank = %d\n",rank);

     MPI_Barrier(PETSC_COMM_WORLD);
 PetscFinalize();
     return 0;
 }
```

However, I got undefined reference errors to `PETSC_COMM_WORLD`, `PetscInitialize` and other junk, when I tried to compile using mpic++

I am now trying to use `build` and cmake. This is my attempt at a `CMakeLists`

```
 CMAKE_MINIMUM_REQUIRED(VERSION 2.8)

 PROJECT(checkMPI)

 SET(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake-modules")

 set(PETSC_ARCH linux-gnu)
 set(PETSC_DIR l${PROJECT_SOURCE_DIR}/third-party/petsc)

 FIND_PACKAGE(PETSc REQUIRED)

 INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${PETSC_INCLUDES})
 ADD_DEFINITIONS(${PETSC_DEFINITIONS})

 ADD_EXECUTABLE(checkMPI checkMPI.cpp)

 TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(checkMPI ${PETSC_LIBRARIES})
```

In addition, I have a directory `cmake-modules` containing the cmake-modules for PETSc

However, when I try to generate the makefile by typing `ccmake ..` and then `c`, I get the output

```
CMake Error at cmake-modules/FindPETSc.cmake:127 (message):
   The pair PETSC_DIR=l/directory/HPC/third-party/petsc
   PETSC_ARCH=linux-gnu do not specify a valid PETSc installation
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   CMakeLists.txt:10 (FIND_PACKAGE)

 CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:108
(message):
   PETSc could not be found.  Be sure to set PETSC_DIR and PETSC_ARCH.
   (missing: PETSC_INCLUDES PETSC_LIBRARIES PETSC_EXECUTABLE_RUNS)
 Call Stack (most recent call first):
   /usr/share/cmake/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:315
```

Anyone can help?

Answer (score 1):

Based on [FindPETSC.cmake](https://github.com/jedbrown/cmake-modules/blob/master/FindPETSc.cmake) it seems that the default options for `PETSC_ARCH` are:

```
linux-gnu-c-debug 
linux-gnu-c-opt
x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu 
i386-unknown-linux-gnu
```

or the one you have used in case of the [manual build](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/installation.html).

CMake tries to find file `${PETSC_DIR}/${PETSC_ARCH}/include/petscconf.h` or 
`${PETSC_DIR}/bmake/${PETSC_ARCH}/petscconf.h`.